# ReferenceError: sass is not defined - Sass.js

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm trying to use [SassJS](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to compile SCSS to CSS.

From SassJS's documentation, it says I can use the compiler by doing the following:

```
<script src="dist/sass.js"></script>
<script>
    var scss = '$someVar: 123px; .some-selector { width: $someVar; }';
    sass.compile(scss, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
</script>
```

And this is what I have done:

```
<script src="js/vendor/sassjs/dist/sass.js">
<script>
    sass.compile(this.code.css, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
</script>
```

And I have double-checked that a: I have loaded the `sass.js` script successfully and b: I have checked `this.code.css` contains SCSS code.

However, I get the following error when I try to run my script:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sass is not defined
```

I really don't understand what I am missing, or what is missing from the documentation, that is preventing me from getting this working. I think I'm pushing the boat out trying to find somebody else on SO that knows about this library and can relate to this issue but it's worth a shot.

What am I missing?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the SassJS source, maybe try `var sass = new Sass()` to declare it?

Comment: @Li357 - top marks for speed!! Please add that as an answer and I will accept it. Not sure why the documentation couldn't suggest that but glad it's working now :)

Comment: Done. Glad to help! I'll submit a PR to the repo to revise the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is lacking the most crucial part. SassJS [declares a global constructor](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/src/sass.js#L9), `Sass`. Construct it:

```
var sass = new Sass();
sass.compile(this.code.css, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```